c++ is_integral_v<T> doesn't compile with templates
I want to declare a self-defined printing function to speed up std::cout when dealing with integer types. However, the code below doesn't compile:
template <typename T>
static inline void print(T value)
{
    if (std::is_integral_v<T>)
    {
        if (value < 0) putchar('-'), value = -value;
        if (value > 9) print(value / 10);
        putchar(value % 10 + '0');
    }
    else std::cout << value;
}

int main()
{
    print("This is not an integer type.");
}

Compile error message:
'%': not valid as left operand has type 'T', with [T=const char *]
'/': not valid as left operand has type 'T', with [T=const char *]
...

But in fact, is_integral_v<const char*> is false so (theoretically) it can run perfectly in runtime.
Are there any alternatives? Or maybe there's something I did wrong?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Both branches of the if need to be valid (no diagnosable errors) regardless of the value being tested.   In your code, value/10 and value % 10 need to be valid, which is not the case if value is a const char * (e.g. a string literal) - since the check is done at run time.   To do a compile-time check, which will discard the invalid branch at compile time, you need to use if constexpr.

You need to use constexpr-if in your traits check:
if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
// ^^^^^^^^^

Demo
